# How to avoid so many queries in Django with reverse foreign keys

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

these are my models (simplified):

**Models:**

```
class Tariff(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=18, decimal_places=3, blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=18, decimal_places=3, blank=True, null=True)
    datefrom = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    dateto = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'Tariff'


class Service(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'Service'

class CalendarValue(models.Model):
    calendar = models.ForeignKey(Calendar, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'CalendarValue'
```

**Serializer:**

```
class AvailabilitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sum_cost = serializers.DecimalField(18, 3)
    sum_price = serializers.DecimalField(18, 3)
    service__id = serializers.IntegerField()
    service__name = serializers.CharField()
    calendarvalue = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Tariff
        fields = ('name', 'sum_cost', 'sum_price', 'service__id', 'service__name', 'calendarvalue')

    def get_calendarvalue(self, tariff):
        start_date = self.context.get('datefrom')
        end_date = self.context.get('dateto')
        service = Service.objects.get(id=tariff['service__id'])
        return CalendarValueSerializer(CalendarValue.objects.filter(service=service,
                                                                    date__range=[start_date, end_date]), read_only=True,
                                       many=True).data
```

This works pefectly, I get all tariffs, with their services and all calendar values per each services.
But I notice that it mades a query per each Service to get its Calendarvalue.
Is there any way to get all data without so many queries?
Thanks.

**My view**

```
queryset = Tariff.objects.filter(datefrom__lte=start_date, dateto__gte=end_date)
queryset = queryset.filter(service__city=city_code)

# group by
queryset = queryset.values('name', 'service__id', 'service__name')\
    .annotate(sum_cost=Sum('cost'), sum_price=Sum('price'), min_datefrom=Min('datefrom'), max_dateto=Max('dateto'))\
    .order_by('service__id', 'name')

context = {'datefrom': start_date, 'dateto': end_date}

serializer = AvailabilitySerializer(queryset, many=True, context=context)

return serializer.data
```

I have read about prefetch_related, but I don't know how implement it.
Thanks.

Comment: [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

Comment: Can you show your view / how you obtain the queryset for this serializer? Apart from `prefetch_related` and probably few other tunings, you definitely could change `.filter(service=service, ...)` to `.filter(service_id=tariff['service__id'], ...)` to skip one query.